# wp_query order by post status no funciona

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

estoy tratando de ordenar una consulta en wp_query por el post_status pero no me funciona, busque que podría ser y encontré algunas sugerencia como por ejemplo agregar los siguientes argumentos:

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 'suppress_filters' => true, 'ignore_custom_sort' => true.
```

Pero ninguno funciono para mi, esta es mi consulta:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array('wc-processing', 'wc-enviado', 'wc-envio-parcial', 'wc-failed', 'wc-cancelled', 'wc-pending'),
            'orderby'   => 'post_status',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            "paged" => $page,
            'date_query'     => array(
                'after' => $after,
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => '_payment_method',
                    'value' => array('payulatam', 'payu_latam_sdk_pls', 'payu_latam_sdk_baloto_plsb', 'payu_latam_sdk_bolet_plsb', 'payu_latam_sdk_efecty_plse', 'payu_latam_sdk_baloto_plspse'),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'dropshippers',
                    'value' => '"' . $dropshipper . '"',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            ),
            'fields' => 'ids'
        );
        $resp = new WP_Query($args);
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Intenta poner el argumento así: `array('orderby'  => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC'), 'meta_key' => 'post_status');`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero el campo 'post_status' no es un meta value y por ende esto no ayuda a solucionar mi problema

Comment: Prueba entonces con `posts_orderby`, como se indica en [esta respuesta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193410).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no pude dar solución a mi necesidad utilizando WP_QUERY con WC_Order_Query conseguí algo un poco mejor pero al parecer solo me ordenaba los pedidos por pagina y no en total que es como yo los necesito por lo que decide hacer la consulta con sql directamente en la db, aqui dejo la consulta por si a alguien le puede ser de ayuda:

```
        global $wpdb;

        $sqltoOrders = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT p.ID FROM 
        `wp_posts` p, `wp_postmeta` pm, `wp_postmeta` pm2
        WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id and p.ID = pm2.post_id
        AND p.post_type = 'shop_order' 
        AND p.post_status IN (" . "'" . implode("', '", $status) . "'" . ")
        AND p.post_date > '$after'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_payment_method'
        AND pm.meta_value IN (" . "'" . implode("', '", $paymentMethods) . "'" . ")
        AND pm2.meta_key = 'dropshippers'
        AND pm2.meta_value LIKE %s ORDER BY p.$orderby $order LIMIT $limit OFFSET $OFFSET;", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like('"' . $dropshipper . '"') . '%'));
```